# Angular JS - dynamic url params and custom url access redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, url-routing, url-parameters

I'm just trying to get this to work:

```
 .....
   .when('/channel/:id/:slug',{
            templateUrl:'views/channel/index.html',
            controller:'Channel',
            publicAccess:true,
            sessionAccess:true
          })
   .....
    app.controller('Channel', ['$scope','$routeParams', function ($scope,$routeParams) {

    }]);


    app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $route) {

      var routesOpenToSession = [];

      angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route, path) {
        console.log(path);
        console.log(route);
        route.sessionAccess && (routesOpenToSession.push(path));
      });

      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextLoc, currentLoc) {

        var closedToSession = (-1 === routesOpenToSession.indexOf($location.path()));

        if(closedToSession && $rootScope.session.id_user) {
          $location.path('/');
        }
      });
    });
```

why i can't access the page via `site.com/channel/9/my-slug` also if `$rootScope.session.id_user` exists  and `sessionAccess:true` ?

i get redirected to `/` , while any other static url are ok using sessionAccess:true  for example `channel/staticparam` is ok but with dynamic params it won't work

this is the console log result :

[image]

Comment: 'channel' != 'channels'

Comment: there is a typo in url. on first look

Comment: sorry yeah a typo i also added the main cause of the redirect !

Comment: not taking to account a lot of BL logic, do you have same issue, when just do a try to open a route?  are you using html5mode,which ignores hashes # in url?

Comment: @EugeneP nope only with this url the other urls are all ok and perfectly working, no not using and not gonna use html5 mode ;P

Comment: I start believe that closedToSession is always true, + session id object is true. http://plnkr.co/edit/B4glcHZwht48wezJ5NiE?p=preview I have created a sample. maybe it will help you to understand the issue

Comment: @EugeneP thanks yes it's a problem with closedToSession but actually i can't get why , could it be that having dynamic params it brokes something in there?

Comment: okay. what do you expect from **routesOpenToSession.indexOf**??  in your case **routesOpenToSession** is collection of available url patterns,  **$location.path()** - is actual url. It will never be found in pattern collection

Comment: @EugeneP sure but how to make it works with the regexp i'm dumb on regexp man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed sorry for the stupid question:

```
/*Not logged redirects*/
app.run(['$rootScope','$location','$route', function ($rootScope, $location,$route) {

   var routesOpenToPublic = [];

    angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {

      if(route.publicAccess){ routesOpenToPublic.push(route.regexp); }

    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, nextLoc, currentLoc) {

     var next_url_regexp = nextLoc.$$route.regexp;
    //redirect for not logged users users
     if(routesOpenToPublic.indexOf(next_url_regexp) < 0){

      $location.path('/auth/login');

     }

    });
}]);
/*Logged redirects*/
app.run(['$rootScope','$location','$route', function ($rootScope, $location, $route) {

  if($rootScope.session && $rootScope.session.id_user){

    var routesOpenToSession = [];

    angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {

      if(route.sessionAccess){ routesOpenToSession.push( route.regexp);}

    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, nextLoc, currentLoc) {

     var next_url_regexp = nextLoc.$$route.regexp;
    //redirect for not allowed session users
     if(routesOpenToSession.indexOf(next_url_regexp) < 0){

      $location.path('/');

     }

    });
  }

 }]);
```

i needed to check the route regexp and not the static url path